# I need some clarification on which of these test is 100% a unit test, by the standards of unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I have two pieces of code that tests API endpoints, I know that unit tests do not make HTTP request to the server, as I am building an API service with a dummy data (just using arrays and other data structures to hold data). I would like to know which of these is truly a unit test (by the true definition of what unit test is)

I have read many tutorials on TDD, and BDD, and I understand that the first version of code is acceptance test, my question is, in many tutorials, this first version is called a unit test, but some say it's acceptance test. I'm a little confused

```
// first version -- the one I believe to be acceptance test

it('should return a list of meetups that meets the search criteria', (done) => {
    agent
     .get('/api/v1/meetups/search')
     .query({ searchTerm: 'meetup 1' })
     .expect(200)
     .end((err, res) => {
         if (err) return done(err);
         res.body.status.should.equal(200);
         res.body.data.should.be.an('array');
         res.body.data.length.should.be.greaterThan(0);
         done();
     });
});

// second version -- using sinon to mock req and res object used in the route handler function

it('can search for meetups by topic', () => {
    const req = {
        query: {
            searchTerm: 'Sample Meetup'
        }
    };

    const res = {
          status() { },
          send() { }
    };

    res.status = sinon.stub(res, 'status').returns(res);
    res.send = sinon.stub(res, 'send').returns(res);

    myController.searchMeetups(req, res);
    res.status.firstCall.args[0].should.equal(200);
    res.send.firstCall.args[0].should.have.property('data');
    res.send.firstCall.args[0].data.length.should.be.greaterThan(0);
 });
```

Test works, for both versions, I want a clarification on the API acceptance test, if its a suitable unit test for APIs

Answer (score 0):

Opinions ahoy:

The second approach is absolutely a unit test.

The first approach is a little closer to an acceptance test, although I would prefer to call it a *functional* test. Presumably any backend database etc. is still mocked out.

The question you didn't ask is, which approach is better for testing a REST API? In my opinion, the *clear answer* is the first approach. This gives you a series of tests that mimic as closely as possible the experience of an actual API user, it allows you to make clear and concise statements about the response and header values returned for each test, etc.

Keep the unit tests for your individual model methods, make functional tests for your controller methods. That's my $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

What you have here is indeed rather an acceptance test. It would also probably qualify as an integration test as well.

In this test, you are testing (wild guess - I don't know what your service does precisely, but hopefully you will get the idea):

- the fact that your server is correctly running
- probably one or several authentication methods that verify that the user has all necessary rights to request this URI
- probably a lot of other middleware stuff, preparing your request correctly, formatting your data, etc.
- maybe a few back and forths with a database
- probably a little bit of tooling for logging, debugging, etc.
- the core functionality of your service (returning a list of meetups in a correct format)

This is a lot of stuff for just one test! And a lot of things that can go wrong if just one line in the hundreds of lines of code managing all of this (some you wrote, some others wrote) have one single mistake in it. And at the end, the only thing you care about is an array with a few items, which is the functionality that your user expects, or `accepts`. This is why we call that `UAT` (or User Acceptance Tests).

You can also say that this is an `integration` test, as you are testing separate parts of your application: the server, and the database.

You can also hear about `E2E` (end-to-end) tests: that would be for example testing that the frontend also displays correctly all the meetups it retrieved from the backend you just tested. And many other types of tests...

Unit tests really test the smallest testable units of code you can find. In your scenario, there are a loooooot of functions in the lifetime of your request. Given parameter X, will function Y always return Z? How about function A, B, C, D...?

Put otherwise: if your test above fails, would you know what part of your code fails? What if there are 2 issues in your code, but since the request fails at the first error, how can you know? Also: how can you make sure that very part will never fail again?

Writing tests is a bit tedious, and there are many ways to do it right. Sometimes it's impossible (or very difficult) to test one function without any other dependancy (for example a function that calls a database), and you can not be expected to test 100% of a very very large project. But you should aim for a "large enough" number there.

And sometimes an issue is in the "glue" between unit-tested code. A networking issue may happen between perfectly fine functions, or race conditions, or... and in that case you need integration tests.